# Null point exception at variable img(while fetching albums of an artist

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch all the albums of an artist, i tried the below code but didn't help..

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.getContentUri("external", click_no);  
final String artist_name = MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.ALBUM;
final String artist_image_path=MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.ALBUM_ART;
final String[]columns={artist_name,artist_image_path};
//String  String_id = //MediaStore.Audio.Artists._ID
//+ "=?";
int ii=0;
String orderBy = MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.ALBUM;
Cursor  cursor = managedQuery(uri, columns,null,null,null);
//String_id, whereVal, orderBy);
if(cursor != null){
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        img[ii]= cursor.getString(1);
        ii=ii+1;    
    }
}
```

Comment: show where you have declared `img`

Comment: String[] img; its a  class variable..or global you may say...

Comment: @Raghunandan ..........?

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava show us where you declare `img`.

Comment: @Raghunandan i have a few questions to ask...have u worked with coverflow?(or any other such thing which uses a few adapters)?

Comment: you mean carousel yes i used renderscript code provided by google

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43017/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-ankit-srivastava)

Comment: @Raghunandan i messaged u on chat

Answer (score 0):

try my code. Just pass filePath to it.

```
private void showMetaData(String filePath){
        MediaMetadataRetriever metaDataRetriver= new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        metaDataRetriver.setDataSource(filePath);

        try {
            byte[] art= metaDataRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap songImage= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0,               art.length);
            yourImageView.setImageBitmap(songImage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("TAG", e.toString());
        }

        try {
            yourSongTitleTextView.setText(metaDataRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("TAG", e.toString());
        }

        try {
            yourAlbumNameTextView.setText(metaDataRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("TAG", e.toString());
        }

        try {
            yourArtistNameTextView.setText(metaDataRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.v("TAG", e.toString());
        }
    }
```